# belongsToMany with nullable foreign - Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, has-and-belongs-to-many

in my Laravel project i get this database structure:

**Products**

- Id
- Name

**Orders**

- Id
- Total

**Order_Product**

- Product_id **(nullable)**
- Order_Id
- Details

In my Order model I make **belongsToMany** retaltionship with Product model:

```
public function products() {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('Details');
}
```

The Problem is when I try to get the Order Products Collection

```
$order->products();
```

I don't get rows **with nullable product_id**, Any solution please ? Thank you.

Comment: That's how it should work, you that product_id doesn't reference any record in the products table. Are you trying to get all of the pivot table records?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, yes exactly I want to get all pivot table records, did you know how please ?

Comment: You want to get all of the records as a Product instance? or you don't mind getting it as array?

Comment: Yes as a Product instance.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel support "Null Object Pattern" since version 5.5 which allows you to define a default model that will be returned if the given relationship is null.

Try using the following code:

```
public function products() {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withDefault()->withPivot('Details');
}
```

Comment: Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::withDefault()

Comment: Still the same problem undefined method

Comment: You're right, sorry, it is for The belongsTo, hasOne, hasOneThrough, and morphOne relationships only, my bad.

Comment: So no solution for this situatuion, with belongsToMany ?

Comment: Not that I'm familiar with unfortunately (as you actually want to get an instance of product with null attributes). Why do you have an order without a product pivot? I mean what is the meaning or target of these records?

Comment: Beceause user choice products from products table or, create his custom product and for this second way It's not necessary ti save the custom product in the products table, I save only the product details with null id

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you don't get "nullable" products because you have a relation Order->Products. When you call $order->products(), eloquent tries to get all **Product entities** that are connected to your Order via **product_id** field. So, if field is empty, then you can't get **Product** because there is no connection.
One of the solutions is:

1. create another entity like **OrderLine(Order_Product table)**; add methods like $orderLine->details() and relation to **Product** like $orderLine->product()
2. add relation to **OrderLine** inside Order - $order->line() or $order->info() etc. -> **Order hasMany OrderLine**
3. then use $order->line() to get an order's details and products (if exists)

p.s. I've compiled it in my head so it might need some code adjustments.
Good luck

Comment: @Malek did my answer help you? I'm really curious with that.